# Getting Syncfusion Flutter Range Selector min and max onChanged in Flutterflow?

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I'm trying to set up a SF Range Selector as a custom widget on FlutterFlow, and I need to pass the min and max selected values to some local state variables.

I have the initial values set with

`final SfRangeValues dateValues = SfRangeValues(2004.0, 2008.0);`

and set the initial slider positions with

`initialValues: dateValues`

now what should I put in onChanged to set the local state variables sliderMin and sliderMax?

`onChanged: ???`

I'm new to dart and at a bit of a loss, so thanks for any help!

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Comment: thanks for the warning. was aware, just trying to ascertain if the product will even work in this use case at all.

Answer (score 0):

In the onChanged callback, there is no need to specify anything. It is used to retrieve the start and end values of the SfRangeSelector pointer, you can use these values and perform any other operation. We have shared the SB sample location below for your reference.

Sample link: https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/range-selector/selection

source link: https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/blob/master/lib/samples/sliders/range_selector/range_selector_with_selection.dart

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/range-selector/basic-features#handle-onchangestart-onchanged-and-onchangeend-callbacks